# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на блок его значение передавалось во всплывающее окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть блоки-цвета при выборе которых при нажатии кнопки заказать передавалось значение цвета, всплывающее окно на Bootstrap 4

```css
.colorblock {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: black;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: red;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal546">
  <div class="product__buy_button">
    Заказать
  </div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal546" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel545" style="color: black">Заявка</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
          <img class="product__image" src="product.jpg">
          <p>Цвет: </p>
          <form action="success.php" method="POST">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Введите имя" required="" style="border-radius: 20px;width: 300px; height:40px; margin: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Введите телефон" required="" style="border-radius: 20px;width: 300px; height:40px; padding-left: 20px;">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="hidden" name="title" value="Широкие полный комплект">
            <button class="btn_red" style="width: 200px; height:40px;background-color:red;border-radius: 20px;margin:10px; ">Отправить</button>
          </form>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не редактируйте блок после правки, или отформатируйте чтобы легко было скопировать в ответ. Теперь по делу вас интересует именно бутстраповский js или подойдет нативный?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Мне главное реализовать, какой js не имеет значения, спасибо за редактирование

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, как-то так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".colorblock").click(function() {
    $(".colorblock").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
  var arrColors = {
    '#000000': 'Черный',
    '#ff0000': 'Красный',
    '#008000': 'Зеленый',
    '#0000ff': 'Синий',
    '#ffff00': 'Желтый'
  };

  rgb2Hex = s => s.match(/[0-9]+/g).reduce((a, b) => a + (b | 256).toString(16).slice(1), '#')
  $('#myModal546').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    if ($(".colorblock").hasClass("active")) {
      currentColor = rgb2Hex($(".colorblock.active").css('background-color'));
      $(".change-color").html("Цвет: " + arrColors[currentColor]);
    }
  })

});
```

```css
.colorblock {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.colorblock.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: black;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: red;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
</a>
<button type="button" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal546" class="modal-open">
  <div class="product__buy_button">
    Заказать
  </div>
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal546" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel545" style="color: black">Заявка</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
          <img class="product__image" src="product.jpg">
          <p class="change-color">Цвет: </p>
          <form action="success.php" method="POST">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Введите имя" required="" style="border-radius: 20px;width: 300px; height:40px; margin: 10px;padding-left: 20px;">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Введите телефон" required="" style="border-radius: 20px;width: 300px; height:40px; padding-left: 20px;">
            <input class="pop-up__form_input" type="hidden" name="title" value="Широкие полный комплект">
            <button class="btn_red" style="width: 200px; height:40px;background-color:red;border-radius: 20px;margin:10px; ">Отправить</button>
          </form>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , подскажите, как можно исправить возможную ошибку нажатия кнопки без выбранного цвета?

Comment: внесла проверку

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите правильно ли я присвоил значение input?
$('#colorinput').val(arrColors[currentColor]);

Comment: вероятно да, в коде посмотрите

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, с моим новым вопросом

Answer (score 2):

Вот на JQ

```
$('.colorblock').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

```js
const mtext = document.getElementById('modal-text');

$('.colorblock').click(function(e) {
  mtext.innerHTML = $(this).css('background-color');
});
```

```css
.colorblock {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="colorblock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="background-color: black;"></div>
<div class="colorblock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="colorblock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="background-color: green;"></div>
<div class="colorblock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
<div class="colorblock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Цвет</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-text">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я хотел спросить можно ли сделать так, чтобы всплывающее окно появлялось после нажатия на кнопку Заказать, а не на сам цвет, и в это окно передавалось название цвета а не rgb, если так можно подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

Comment: Да это просто показать как можно получить, можно на нативном.

Comment: Подскажите как, пожалуйста

Comment: показать окно или нативный подход ?

Comment: подправил. А если нужно чтобы писало именно текст нужно добавить data атрибут и туда написать текст, по хорошему можно все на js переписать.